# IIFE strange behavior linked to variables declared with let or var

Tags: javascript, function, var, let, iife

I try to understand why the variable 'Permissions' will be typeof 'function' when Permissions declared with var but typeof 'object' when declared with let (which is the excepted behavior)

With 'var' - Permissions is typeof 'function'

```js
var Permissions;

(function (Permissions) {
    Permissions[Permissions["ADMIN"] = 0] = "ADMIN";
    Permissions[Permissions["READ_ONLY"] = 1] = "READ_ONLY";
})(Permissions || (Permissions = {}));

console.log(typeof Permissions);
```

With 'let' - Permissions is typeof 'object'

```js
let Permissions;

(function (Permissions) {
    Permissions[Permissions["ADMIN"] = 0] = "ADMIN";
    Permissions[Permissions["READ_ONLY"] = 1] = "READ_ONLY";
})(Permissions || (Permissions = {}));

console.log(typeof Permissions);
```

I excepted both scenario to be 'object'. why using 'var' Permissions is typeof 'function'?

Comment: try just `var Permissions; console.log(typeof Permissions)` it has nothing to do with IIFE - all to do with [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) and the subtle difference between var and let

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a variable with `var` in a global scope makes it a property of `window`.
Since you haven't initialized it, it's actually pointing to the existing `window.Permissions` property, which is a constructor of [`navigator.permissions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API).

`let` works differently and declares a separate variable in the current scope:

```js
console.log(Permissions);
console.log(navigator.permissions.__proto__ === Permissions.prototype);

var test = 'test';
console.log(window.test);
```

If you put your `var` into a function scope, it would work like `let`:

```js
(function(){

  var Permissions;

  (function (Permissions) {
      Permissions[Permissions["ADMIN"] = 0] = "ADMIN";
      Permissions[Permissions["READ_ONLY"] = 1] = "READ_ONLY";
  })(Permissions || (Permissions = {}));

  console.log(typeof Permissions);

})();
```

Also works as `let` in a module scope:

```html
<script type="module">

var Permissions;

(function (Permissions) {
    Permissions[Permissions["ADMIN"] = 0] = "ADMIN";
    Permissions[Permissions["READ_ONLY"] = 1] = "READ_ONLY";
})(Permissions || (Permissions = {}));

console.log(typeof Permissions);

</script>
```

With this and other many problems inherited to `var` I treat `var` as legacy and dangerous and prohibit it with ESLint.